# How to avoid long-lived tcp connection in XMPP so that server can handle millions of users?

Tags: xmpp

If answer is "using xmpp BOSH", then to use BOSH, we need to have in-between CM (Connection Manager) server that would interact with xmpp server. So that xmpp client to CM interaction will then happen over normal http protocol (which will be scalable), but again CM to xmpp server will happen using long-live tcp connection which will cause scalability issue.

How can we make xmpp client-server more scalable??

Answer (score 0):

Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP (BOSH) is basically a technology to keep the connection alive to allow the system to send and receive the data to and fro. To be able to use xmpp over the HTTP, you will have to use BOSH.

For you concern about the scalability, you can basically use components which are meant for scalability such as Nginx a component in place of Apache httpd, also there are many connection managers available with Punjab being the most scalable of all. If you are using Openfire as a XMPP server, it has a prebuilt connection manager which has proved scalability.

Comment: Thanks!!! So, you mean to say that Punjab can hold thousands of long-live connection to XMPP server, while talking to xmpp clients over http. I understand that BOSH must be used when we want xmpp over http based clients, but the question is should BOSH be used for scalibility as well since BOSH doesn't require long-live tcp connection between clients and CM server(e.g. Punjab)??

Comment: BOSH actually requires a bidirectional long lived tcp connection between client and server. You can understand it by just reading the abstract on RFC for BOSH at http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html. As far as I understand BOSH is not a technology to live for high scalability, it should be used if you want the instant collaboration between client and server.